# RequireJS not working with Shim'ed jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

The plugins almost always insist on loading before jQuery. And they should not do this due to my use of the shim setting.

In my main.js i have these settings:

```
requirejs.config({
   paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': '../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
        'select2': 'vendor/select2',
        'jshashtable': 'vendor/jshashtable-2.1',
        'jquery.numberformatter': 'vendor/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min',
        'jq-datepicker': 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker',
        'jq-datepicker.da': 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.da'
    }, 

    // Use shim for plugins that does not support ADM
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
        'select2': ['jquery'],
        'jq-datepicker': ['jquery'],
        'jshashtable': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.numberformatter': ['jquery', 'jshashtable']
    },
    enforceDefine: true
});
```

Later in this file I have the following:

```
// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'jq-datepicker'],
function ($) {

    console.log('Require.JS loaded');

    // Init datepickers
    // Docs: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        language: 'da',
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        autoclose: true
    });

});
```

But I get this error all the time:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function)
```

And I can see in my Chrome Network tab that it is loaded before jQuery.

Now I tried adding the `enforceDefine: true` after looking around here on stackoverflow, but with no luck. I tried moving the requirejs.config to my html page. And I tried loading jQuery from a local file. All with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've tested your example and didn't see any issues: http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/tHkHw/ I removed the enforceDefine and jq-datepicker.da (couldnt find it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you shim jquery too?

```
shim: {
    jQuery: {
       exports: 'jquery'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
       exports : 'jquery'
     },
    'select2': {
       exports :'jquery'
     },
     ...
},
```

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this but with no luck at all. Right now I just load jQuery outside of RequireJS.

Comment: bootstrap: {
    deps: ['jQuery'],
    exports: 'jQuery'
},

Comment: I fixed this issue, but it's some time ago. You get the accept as in most cases this would be the truth. And you have the most upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it `$` you want to export ?

```
shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jqueryuitouchpunch': {
            deps: ['jqueryui']
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
       exports : 'jquery'
     },
    'select2': {
       exports :'jquery'
     },
     ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure you load jQuery before your plugin, using define:

```
// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function ($) {
    define(['jq-datepicker'], function() {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
          language: 'da',
          keyboardNavigation: false,
          autoclose: true
    });
  });

});
```